# MFC: Access m_wndToolBar from CView?

Tags: mfc

I need to go a little beyond the standard MFC handling of enabling and disabling a toolbar item.  That part works and is great.  But I have a `CTreeView` where I need to also enable/disable a toolbar item based on what is selected on the tree view.   I can get the `CMainFrame` pointer via `AfxGetMainWnd()` but the `m_wndToolBar` in inaccessible.

What is the recommended way to handle this in MFC?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is to simply add `GetMyToolbar` public method to your `CMainFrame` class, that will return the pointer to `m_wndToolBar`.

```cpp
CMFCToolBar* CMainFrame::GetMyToolbar()
{
   return &m_wndToolBar;
}
```

Comment: Doing that the toolbar didn't update.  Turns out the correct way to do what I needed was to setup a UPDATE_COMMAND_UI in the CTreeView for the Toolbar item.  Then use the `pCmdUI->Enable()` to setup the correct state.  Nice.

Comment: @df234987 I think that is because a doc style project is designed to use the `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` mechanism. So if you do things manually they probably get overridden by the mechanism. Good you sorted it. Maybe add your own answer.